# How to amend 2023 federal return after refund has been issued?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

I e-filed our 2023 federal taxes early last month, with a refund coming our way.

Yesterday I received a letter from our mortgage company along with an adjusted form 1098; the letter explained they had miscalculated and misreported the interest and points paid last year on the original 1098 they provided back in January.

I double-checked the forms against my records and it looks like I have over-claimed my interest and points paid by about $1400.

I thought I would work on amending and filing an amended return this evening, hoping to correct it before my return was processed.

Checking my bank statement today it appears the IRS deposited the refund into my checking account overnight. What lucky timing!

My question: How do I go about amending my return and returning a portion of my refund now that it has been processed? I'm guessing the refund will be reduced by around $200.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter if your refund was already processed or not, you'd do the same thing: file an amended return with a payment for the difference calculated from the original return.

You can provide bank account details for them to debit (see [the instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040x#en_US_202402_publink11362hd0e3070)), or mail a paper return with a check (the check will be processed much faster than the amended return itself).

Comment: I don't believe you can just provide bank account details if you owe money and expect the IRS to debit the payment.  If you owe money, you need to explicitly make a payment, either by mailing a check or using one of the options on the IRS's [Make a Payment page](https://www.irs.gov/payments).

Comment: @BenMiller that's what I linked to. You can initiate ACH debit there.

Comment: I apologize if I misunderstood your answer.  I got the impression that you were suggesting that you could simply provide your bank account details on the return, which does work if you are getting a refund, but does not work if you need to make a payment.